# Expandable sections on /tools page are not accessible

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, accessibility

I'm newly suffering from carpal tunnel syndrome and having to adapt how I use the computer. On the /tools page of Stack Exchange sites, the links for the section headers, used to expand the sections to show the full lists, instead of just 3 items, are not accessible. They are not real link tags you see, just <h3> tags with style cursor:pointer and onclick handlers, so unlike real links they cannot be activated by keyboard or voice control, only by clicking. I'm sure this is quite fixable as all the other widget/button things on Stack Exchange seem to work fine.

(Also, personally I'd rather like it if the sections would remember their expand/collapse state, or if they would just stay expanded.)

The bits I'm talking about are the ones in this picture labelled "Highest voted", "Lowest  voted", etc. (No freehand circles but you understand...)

[image]